# Open CSV, Copy Paste Range to Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am having trouble getting the copied range to paste in the destination workbook. I have a .csv file that will have one worksheet, but the worksheet name will be different each time the .csv is exported. Can someone look over my code and let me know if you see anything that stands out that would be screwing things up.

The code works up until `Target.Copy` (the target range is selected and copied). But the code I have to paste the values to the destination workbook don't seem to be working however.

I will sometimes get this error message:
[image]

```
Sub Opencsv()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook, wkbDest As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim Target As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")
On Error Resume Next
Last = fLastRow(wkbDest)
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FilesToOpen, Format:=4)
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AdvFilter")


With wkbTemp.Sheets(1)
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Set Target = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

Target.Copy

wkbDest.Sheets("AdvFilter").Activate

With wkbDest.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

wkbTemp.Close
End Sub

'==================
Function fLastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Update2:

```
Sub Opencsv2()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim Last As Long


FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & FilesToOpen, Destination:=Cells(Last + 1, "A"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

For Each qt In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AdvFilter").QueryTables
       qt.Delete
Next qt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider importing using [QueryTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198271.aspx) and avoid any need for copy/paste to the clipboard:

```
Sub Opencsv()
   Dim FilesToOpen
   Dim qt As QueryTable

   FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AdvFilter").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FilesToOpen, _
       Destination:=Cells(1, 1))
        .TextFileStartRow = 30
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   End With

   For Each qt In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AdvFilter").QueryTables
       qt.Delete
   Next qt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but only thing that happens is my header moves a column over from A3:D3 to B3:E3.

Comment: Not quite understanding. No data at all imports to spreadsheet? Please post a bit of content to reproduce. You can specify top left corner of data import in `Destination` arg, here being `Cells(1,1)`. Curious to hear data starts at `B3`. You may have empty rows and cols in csv. Please post sample.

Comment: The above update2 code works. The only problem I have is getting it to the start at the correct destination. I need it to start a row or two below the last row with data on AdvFilter worksheet. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The import starts at A1 which wipes out my header.

Comment: Got it to work. `Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3)`